# Inno setup - adding an animated gif

Tags: inno-setup, gif

im trying to implement an animated gif on my wizard page. I think that Inno Setup does not provide a straigth way to do it. But is it possible to use several bitmaps that will be replaced after a few secconds over and over again.
Here is my Code (for now, only one bmp is appearing):

```
Source: "{#GetUsbDrive}\First_Image.bmp"; Flags: dontcopy
Source: "{#GetUsbDrive}\Seccond_Image.bmp"; Flags: dontcopy
Source: "{#GetUsbDrive}\Third_Image.bmp"; Flags: dontcopy

[Code]
var

  Page: TWizardPage;
  Image: TBitmapImage;

procedure InitializeWizard;

Page := CreateCustomPage(wpWelcome, 'random text', 'random text');
              
begin
 ExtractTemporaryFile('Lasal 1 Class Setup.bmp');
  with TBitmapImage.Create(WizardForm) do
  begin
    Parent := Page.Surface;
    Bitmap.LoadFromFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\First_Image.bmp'));
    width:= 670;
    height:= 250;
    Center := true;
    Stretch := true;
    Top :=10;
   end;
end;
```